# Where did Knox go after Lollipop upgrade?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have Samsung Galaxy S4. I use Knox for my work email setup and it worked well.

After upgrading to Lollipop, it disappeared. I can't find it in applications. When it tries to start itself and I type in my password it says:

> Failed to mount knox partition. Restart device.

Is it possible to have it back?

Comment: From [this forum thread](http://androidforums.com/threads/s4-lollipop-update-problems-dummies-guide.836936/), it seems that you have to do full wipe (internal+external storage), then do factory reset. Search for "knox" on that thread.